# Uncaught TypeError TypeError: client.commands.array is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My Discord Bot has v13 version and whatever command I add it gives this error.

I tried the poll command and the lucky number commands.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(set.prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(set.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        var cmd = client.commands.get(command) || client.commands.array().find((x) => x.aliases && x.aliases.includes(command));
        if (!cmd) return message.channel.send(`Komut dosyamda **${command}** adlı bir komut bulamadım.`);
        try {
            cmd.run(client, message, args, set);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `.array()` is no longer a function for Collections. Use `Array.from(client.commands)` or `[...client.commands.values()]`

Comment: I did what she said, this time it gives "command not found error" to every command